# Using a while loop to calculate the factorial of numbers between 0 and 10 in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple program to calculate the factorial of a user inputted value, however, I want to write a program to output the values of the factorials of each number from 0 to 10. (inclusive)

my program:

```
def factorial(n):
    f = 1
    while (n > 0):
        f = f * n
        n = n - 1
    return f
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: are you trying  to do 
`for i in xrange(11):
print factorial(i)` ??

Comment: You're able to write this function but you can't write a `for` loop that calls this function and prints the results? Truly wondrous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably destined for oblivion, but it costs nothing to answer.

```
#your function
def factorial(n):
    f = 1
    while (n > 0):
        f = f * n
        n = n - 1
    return f

#a new function that loop the first one
def factorial_loop(n):
    #in Python 2.x, you should use xrange() instead of range()
    for i in range(n+1):
        print(factorial(i))

factorial_loop(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate your factorial recursive function from 1 to 10 and put the index as your argument.

I urge you to try to do this and code it, in order for you to improve your coding skills.

Hope it helps.